# i run command django-admin startproject dr it shows zsh: command not found: django-admin?

Tags: python, django

i run command `django-admin startproject dr` it show `zsh: command not found: django-admin`[image]

How to solve this problem ?
i also unintall django and reinstall and update pip

```
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip'
```

Comment: Try `python3 -m django startproject dr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/faq/troubleshooting/) you can try this alternative command:

```
 python -m django startproject dr
```

Comment: by using python3 -m django startproject dr it is done